wordpress payment plugin doesn't appear
I face a problem with showing a custom payment option in payment options
Iam sure it is set up correctly but it doesn't appear (like photos)
I also added a js file with some logs to make sure it is working and it did the logs
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Custom Payment Gateway
Description: A custom payment gateway for WooCommerce.
Version: 1.0
Author: Your Name
*/

// Ensure WooCommerce is active
if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {
    // Add custom payment gateway class
    add_action('plugins_loaded', 'my_custom_payment_gateway_init', 5);
    function my_custom_payment_gateway_init() {
        class WC_Gateway_Custom extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
            public function __construct() {
                $this->id = 'custom_gateway';
                $this->icon = ''; // URL to an icon if you want to add
                $this->has_fields = true;
                $this->method_title = __('Custom Gateway', 'woocommerce');
                $this->method_description = __('Description of custom payment gateway', 'woocommerce');

                // Load the settings
                $this->init_form_fields();
                $this->init_settings();

                $this->title = $this->get_option('title');
                $this->description = $this->get_option('description');

                // Save settings
                add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array($this, 'process_admin_options'));
            }

            // Admin options
            public function init_form_fields() {
                $this->form_fields = array(
                    'enabled' => array(
                        'title' => __('Enable/Disable', 'woocommerce'),
                        'type' => 'checkbox',
                        'label' => __('Enable Custom Payment Gateway', 'woocommerce'),
                        'default' => 'yes'
                    ),
                    'title' => array(
                        'title' => __('Title', 'woocommerce'),
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'description' => __('This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', 'woocommerce'),
                        'default' => __('Custom Payment', 'woocommerce'),
                        'desc_tip' => true,
                    ),
                    'description' => array(
                        'title' => __('Description', 'woocommerce'),
                        'type' => 'textarea',
                        'description' => __('This controls the description which the user sees during checkout.', 'woocommerce'),
                        'default' => __('Pay using our custom payment gateway.', 'woocommerce')
                    )
                );
            }

            // Display custom fields on the checkout page
            public function payment_fields() {
                // Description of the payment method
                if ($this->description) {
                    echo wpautop(wp_kses_post($this->description));
                }
                // Add custom fields here
                ?>
                <fieldset>
                    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->id); ?>-custom-field"><?php esc_html_e('Custom Field', 'woocommerce'); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->id); ?>-custom-field" class="input-text" type="text" autocomplete="off">
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
                <?php
            }

            // Payment processing
            public function process_payment($order_id) {
                $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

                // Mark as on-hold (we're awaiting the payment)
                $order->update_status('on-hold', __('Awaiting custom payment', 'woocommerce'));

                // Reduce stock levels
                wc_reduce_stock_levels($order_id);

                // Remove cart
                WC()->cart->empty_cart();

                // Return thank you page redirect
                return array(
                    'result' => 'success',
                    'redirect' => $this->get_return_url($order)
                );
            }
        }
    }

    // Add to WooCommerce
    add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_my_custom_payment_gateway');
    function add_my_custom_payment_gateway($gateways) {
        $gateways[] = 'WC_Gateway_Custom';
        return $gateways;
    }

    // Enqueue JavaScript file
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_gateway_enqueue_script');
    function custom_gateway_enqueue_script() {
        wp_enqueue_script('custom-gateway-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'custom-gateway.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    }
}
?>

I watched a lot of videos and tutorials but none of help (I am running it locally if this help)



This is because you are using new Checkout Block that requires something completely different for custom payment gateways.

WooCommerce has recently changed its Checkout page implementation on its newer versions. Hence, the legacy code may not work. You can try downgrading the WooCommerce version or adhering to the latest checkout code.
